# Right side bar included in component area in Helix3 framework template

Tags: joomla-3.9, helix3

I recently installed a template based on Helix3 framework and I've noticed an inconsistency in the way how pages are created. Specifically, I have created two different menu items

1. list of a single category (e.g. https://webtutordimatematica.it/materie/algebra-di-base/monomi-e-polinomi)
2. list of all categories (e.g. https://webtutordimatematica.it/materie/algebra-di-base )

and for both I set a custom module to appear on the right side. While the module appears correctly in pages of type 1, it doesn't in those pages of type 2. In this last case, the module is wrapped down after the component area.
Then, I went through the inspector and found the culprit.
In pages of type 1 the html code looks like:

```
<div id="sp-component" class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">...</div>
<div id="sp-right" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">...</div>
```

while in those of type 2 it looks like:

```
<div id="sp-component" class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">...
    <div id="sp-right" class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">...</div>
</div>
```

In few words, in this last case, the right side module is inside the component area so it can't be displayed on the right as it should.
Does anyone know whether this is a bug in the framework or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by looking at https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=881561
Another bug of Joomshaper override template.